# Pandas dataframe unique values

Tags: python, pandas

need some help with getting uniqued values from pandas dataframe

i have :

```
    >>> df1
     source    target metric
0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx  10000
1  acx1.xxx  acc1.yyy  10000
```

the goal is to remove unique values based on source+target or target+source. but i can't get this with drop_duplicates.

```
>>> df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['source','target'])
>>> df2
     source    target metric
0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx  10000
1  acx1.xxx  acc1.yyy  10000
```

[updated]

maybe duplicate is not the correct word here so let me explain further

```
id  source  target
0   bng1.xxx.00 bdr2.xxx.00
1   bng1.xxx.00 bdr1.xxx.00
2   bdr3.yyy.00 bdr3.xxx.00
3   bdr3.xxx.00 bdr3.yyy.00
4   bdr2.xxx.00 bng1.xxx.00
5   bdr1.xxx.00 bng1.xxx.00
```

with above , i want to remove the entryies that have for exampl source=target and target=source.

```
0 and 4 = same pair
1 and 5 = same pair
2 and 3 = same pair

end goal will be to keep 0 1 2 or 4 5 3 .
```

Comment: Don't understand what you're trying to do. Please clarify "remove unique values based on source+target or target+source". An example of input and output would help.

Comment: i need to take acc1.yyy + acx1.xxx pair , and make sure there is no entry that matches that OR that matches acx1.xxx + acc1.yyy pair.

Comment: What about the metric column? If there are duplicates, which value should be used? Again, please edit your question to include an example input and your desired output.

Comment: metric. i've updated the post to reflect what i'm looking to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first sort both columns:

```
df1[['source','target']] = df1[['source','target']].apply(sorted,axis=1)
print (df1)
     source    target  metric
0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx   10000
1  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx   10000

df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['source','target'])
print (df2)
     source    target  metric
0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx   10000
```

EDIT:

It seems column `source` need be changed - remove last 3 characters:

```
df1['source1'] = df1.source.str[:-3]
df1[['source1','target']] = df1[['source1','target']].apply(sorted,axis=1)
print (df1)
   id          source       target      source1
0   0  bng1.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00  bdr2.xxx.00
1   1  bng1.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00  bdr1.xxx.00
2   2  bdr3.yyy.00-00  bdr3.yyy.00  bdr3.xxx.00
3   3  bdr3.xxx.00-00  bdr3.yyy.00  bdr3.xxx.00
4   4  bdr2.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00  bdr2.xxx.00
5   5  bdr1.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00  bdr1.xxx.00

df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['source1','target'])
df2 = df2.drop('source1', axis=1)
print (df2)
   id          source       target
0   0  bng1.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00
1   1  bng1.xxx.00-00  bng1.xxx.00
2   2  bdr3.yyy.00-00  bdr3.yyy.00
```

Comment: not working for me. i've updated the post to reflect what i'm looking to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of duplicates is not the same as the one that pandas uses. In pandas two rows are considered duplicates if corresponding entries are the same. In the example below row 1 and row 2 are not duplicates because they have different values for corresponding varaibles, whereas row 3 and 4 are duplicates.

```
df = {'source':['acc1.yyy', 'acx1.xxx', 'acc1.xxx', 'acc1.xxx'], 'target': ['acx1.xxx', 'acc1.yyy', 'acc1.yyy', 'acc1.yyy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
     # source    target
# 0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx
# 1  acx1.xxx  acc1.yyy
# 2  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy
# 3  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy
df.drop_duplicates()
     # source    target
# 0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx
# 1  acx1.xxx  acc1.yyy
# 2  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy
```

For the case that you are mentioning, create a new column that is a tuple of the the source and target columns. Try the following

```
df.loc[:, 'src_tgt'] = pd.Series([tuple(sorted(each)) for each in list(zip(df.source.values.tolist(), df.target.values.tolist()))])
df
     # source    target               src_tgt
# 0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx  (acc1.yyy, acx1.xxx)
# 1  acx1.xxx  acc1.yyy  (acx1.xxx, acc1.yyy)
# 2  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy  (acc1.xxx, acc1.yyy)
# 3  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy  (acc1.xxx, acc1.yyy)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['src_tgt'])
     # source    target               src_tgt
# 0  acc1.yyy  acx1.xxx  (acc1.yyy, acx1.xxx)
# 2  acc1.xxx  acc1.yyy  (acc1.xxx, acc1.yyy)
```

Comment: not working for me. i've updated the post to reflect what i'm looking to achieve